# Inesperada excepción java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

En una clase que define un nivel de un juego posee el siguiente atributo:

private Cell[][] board;

el cual representa cada una de las casillas del tablero de dicho nivel.

Necesito definir un método sobrecargado, que devuelva, por un lado la casilla según 2 int, uno que define la columna y otro la línea de dicha casilla y, por otro lado, que devuelva la casilla pero el parámetro, en este caso, es un objeto tipo posición, el cuál se define igualmente por una fila y la columna.

Mi definición de los métodos es la siguiente:

```
public Cell getCell(int row, int column) throws LevelException {


        if (row <0 || column <0 || row>=getSize() || column>=getSize() ) {
            throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
        }

        return board[row][column];

    }

    public Cell getCell(Position position) throws LevelException {

        if (position.getRow()< 0 || position.getColumn()< 0 || position.getRow()>=getSize() || position.getColumn()>=getSize()) {
            throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
        }

        return board[position.getRow()][position.getColumn()];
    }
```

Los enunciados de  los métodos no los puedo modificar.
Los métodos getRow y getPosition de la clase Position están comprobados que funcionan correctamente, al igual que getSize.
El javadoc del proyecto comenta que los métodos deben lanzar LevelException si la fila o la columna son incorrectas.
Estas pueden ser incorrectas si alguna tiene un valor negativo, superan el tamaño del tablero o lo igualan.

El test que comprueba el funcionamiento de dichos métodos es el siguiente:

```
 try {
            assertEquals(Element.WALL, level.getCell(new Position(0,0)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.EMPTY, level.getCell(new Position(0,1)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.WALL, level.getCell(new Position(0,2)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.PLAYER, level.getCell(new Position(1,0)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.STOP, level.getCell(new Position(1,1)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.EMPTY, level.getCell(new Position(1,2)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.MINE, level.getCell(new Position(2,0)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.EMPTY, level.getCell(new Position(2,1)).getElement());
            assertEquals(Element.GEM, level.getCell(new Position(2,2)).getElement());

            LevelException ex = assertThrows(LevelException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(3,4)));
            assertEquals(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION, ex.getMessage());

            ex = assertThrows(LevelException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(4,3)));
            assertEquals(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION, ex.getMessage());

            PositionException ex2 = assertThrows(PositionException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(-1,0)));
            assertEquals(PositionException.POSITION_ROW_ERROR, ex2.getMessage());

        } catch (LevelException | PositionException e) {
            fail("getCell failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Me falla en la línea:

```
LevelException ex = assertThrows(LevelException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(3,4)));
```

Por consola me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <edu.uoc.nertia.model.exceptions.LevelException> but was: <java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException>

No entiendo cuál puede ser el fallo, el proyecto no me da errores por otro sitio, está comprobado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está trabajando con un objeto vector simple `Object[]` (o una matriz en su caso, pero es lo mismo) y está tratando de obtener una posición que no existe, la excepción **siempre se lanzará** si intenta obtener un posición inexistente de un vector, array o string.

**Lo que puedes hacer:**

En lugar de interactuar directamente con el vector, cree otro método que esté a cargo del vector, cada llamada debe pasar por este método, y este método verificará si el `int` informado es más pequeño que el tamaño de la matriz, de ser así, devolverá la posición, de lo contrario, devuelva nulo o algo más.

o

En lugar de usar un objeto vectorial simple `Object[]`, usa una Collection o Map adecuado, que devuelve un valor nulo en lugar de generar una excepción cuando no se encuentra la posición o la clave.

Comment: No puedo incluir ningún método auxiliar ya que los test comprueban el número de métodos definidos. He añadido una respuesta ya que he conseguido avanzar un poco.

Answer (score 0):

He comprobado que incluyendo el return dentro del if pasa las siguientes líneas del test:

```
LevelException ex = assertThrows(LevelException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(3,4)));
            assertEquals(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION, ex.getMessage());

            ex = assertThrows(LevelException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(4,3)));
            assertEquals(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION, ex.getMessage());
```

La explicación del método es la siguiente:

getCell: si la posición es válida, entonces devuelve el objeto Cell que hay en la
posición indicada como parámetro. En caso contrario, lanza una LevelException
con el mensaje de INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION. Este método está sobrecargado.

A continuación me falla la siguiente comprobación de excepción, es decir:

```
PositionException ex2 = assertThrows(PositionException.class, () -> level.getCell(new Position(-1,0)));
            assertEquals(PositionException.POSITION_ROW_ERROR, ex2.getMessage());
```

He modificado el método de la siguiente forma:

```
public Cell getCell(Position position) throws LevelException{

           if (position.getRow()>=getSize() || position.getColumn()>=getSize()){
               throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
           }else{
               if (position.getRow()<0) {

                   try {
                       throw new PositionException(PositionException.POSITION_ROW_ERROR);
                   } catch (PositionException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }else{
               if (position.getColumn()<0){
                   try {
                       throw  new PositionException(PositionException.POSITION_COLUMN_ERROR);
                   } catch (PositionException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }else{
               return board[position.getRow()][position.getColumn()];
           }}}

   return null;
   }
```

No puedo incluir PositionException en la firma del método por eso uso try...catch, aun así he probado a incluirlo y tengo el mismo error.

La consola muestra:

[ERROR] Position's row cannot be a negative value.